Prove that $tr(T)=\sum _{\lambda \in \sigma_p(T)}\lambda \dim E_\lambda$
$T$ is a compact operator and a Trace-class operator on the Hilbert space $H$, prove that $tr(T)=\sum _{\lambda \in \sigma_p(T)}\lambda \dim E_\lambda$, where $E_\lambda =\ker(\lambda I-T)$.
The definition of $tr$: $$tr(T)=\sum_\alpha\langle Te_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle, $$
where $\{e_\alpha\}$ is  an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space $H$.
The question first asks to prove that  if $M=\mathrm{span}\{f\in H:\exists \lambda\ne 0, s.t. Tf=\lambda f\}$ is dense in $H$, then $tr(T)=\sum_\alpha\langle Te_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle, $ which I have already proved by using Riesz-Schauder theorem.
Then it asks to prove that $tr(T)=\sum_\alpha\langle Te_\alpha,e_\alpha\rangle $ for any $T$ the Trace-class operator, given a fact that when $r(T)=0$, $tr(T)=0.$ (This fact needn't be proved)
So let $H=\overline M\oplus \overline M^{\perp}$. I considered $p\circ T|_{\overline M^\perp}$, where $p:H\to \overline M^{\perp}$ the projection operator.
But $p\circ T|_{\overline M^\perp}$ doesn't  necessarily satisfies $r(p\circ T|_{\overline M^\perp})=0$?
The question says also that this is Lidskii, but the proof of Lidskii seems very complex.

You can use an adapted version of the trigonalisation for Hilbert spaces it should work.

I would try to mimic the proof in finite dimension since you have a compact operator.  An this proof relies on trigonalisation

I know that $\dim M$ is countable, but $\dim \overline M^\perp$ may not be countable. What do you mean by mimicing the proof in finite dimension?

Are you sure that the assumption on the density of $M$ can be omitted ? For example $$T=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ we have ${\rm tr} ,T=2$ but the dimension of $E_1$ is $1.$ Perhaps you should define $E_\lambda=\ker(T-\lambda I)^k,$ where $k$ is the smallest index for which $$\ker(T-\lambda I)^k=  \ker(T-\lambda I)^{k+1}$$

Your example is very good and indeed is a counterexample. Thanks! (This is a question in my textbook. I will go and ask.
